# How do I achieve "Smash TV"?

Tags: achievements, portal-2

*Which* eleven monitors do I have to break to obtain the **Smash TV** achievement?

[image: Portal 2: "Smash TV" achievement badge]

I'm assuming it's the monitors that appear throughout Chapter 8?

But, having just run through Chapter 8 and trying to get this, I've just counted **14** monitors (and only managed to break 8 of them so far).

Have I miscounted?
Are some irrelevant? (maybe the first 3 in the "easy" rooms?)

---

<sup>Can you please use `>!` spoiler markup if you're going to explain *how* to break them; for now I'd just like to know *which* to break.</sup>

Comment: Can you break the same one 11 times?  You can only break them if you hit them with something; some chambers might offer no method to get at them.

Comment: @Nick No, they only break once (unless you mean using the same one on multiple run-throughs? In which case I guess not, but haven't tested). But, so far I've broken them by flinging me or a box at them or by burning with a laser; you don't necessarily have to *hit* them with something.

Comment: You have to do it in one playthrough. Even if you use changelevel, the dialogue will be the 'bless your primate brain one'. At the very least you'll need to smash every one of them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right, I've hit the achievement, and here's the info:

I've now counted 16 monitors in Chapter 8, but you can ignore the first 5, so **you need to break all the monitors from the one found in the test chamber numbered `1/19`, up to the start of Chapter 9**.

### Instruction for breaking each monitor:

#### Chamber 1

> Move the cube to the lower section of the level. Use a ceiling-floor loop to get the cube to high speed then fling it from the opposite wall to the monitor.

#### Chamber 2

> Move a cube to the ceiling using the vertical funnel position that forms the normal solve of the level and drop the funnel to fling the cube at the monitor from the wall in front of it.

#### Chamber 3

> Another cube fling, either using a ceiling-floor loop or funnel to get the cube up to speed for the fling.

#### Chamber 4

> You need to sneak round to behind the turret (I managed to run to the wall next to it before it could kill me, wait and then run again) and carry the turret towards the monitor. As long as you do this with the turret being "OK" (ie, don't let it shut-down) then it will target and shoot the monitor for you. You might have to put it down (as long as it lands correctly).

#### Chamber 5 *(has 2 monitors)*

> The closest monitor is broken by flinging a cube from the opposite wall using a vertical funnel in the centre. Place the launching portal directly under where the funnel hits the wall to ensure you're on target.
>  The second monitor only appears when you reach the exit door, and is broken by the same method but by flinging the cube from the far-right space on the angled launch pad opposite.

#### Chamber 6

> Just step on the aerial faith plate to launch yourself at the monitor.

#### Chamber 11

> Once you've set up your laser (for completing the level) instead place the exit portal on the wall facing the monitor near the target point for the laser. Then maybe tweak the angle of the laser with the box to point it at the monitor for a few seconds.

#### Chamber 12

> When you're setting up the laser to aim at it's target, just point it right a bit (at the monitor) for a few seconds.

#### Chamber 15

> I did this with a double-fling of myself. Set a on the opposite wall and one of the floor below it, step in to the one on the floor then *fall* in to the one on the floor again - this second fall should give you the speed to fling across for the break.

#### Chamber 16

> This one was quite difficult, but basically you have to get hold of a turret and get that to shoot the monitor (as per chamber 4).
>  First, I used blue gel to remove two of the turrets (instead of all three as you would to solve the chamber). Then I carefully placed a portal on only half of where the funnel is hitting the wall and linked it to one on the floor - this means the funnel doesn't "pass through" the portal, so you can effectively sit on that wall. From here you can shoot the other portal in to the wall above the turrets, then reposition the portal that's misaligned on the funnel's wall to let the funnel through. Then you can ride the funnel and drop down on top of the turret.

---

#### Additional monitor

> Once you've started chapter 9, when Wheatley tells you that you're getting close to his lair, you can blow up the monitor using the falling bombs (this is the room that he tries to kill you with the spike plate and conveyor belt).
>  Please note that this *does not contribute to the achievement*.

Comment: Jeez, started from scratch and you beat me to the punch :P  Pretty comprehensive answer though

Comment: @Nick Heh, considering the fact we both had input on the question as I posted it, it is pretty amazing we both post a suitably complete answer only 8 seconds apart. :)

Comment: Easier way for Chamber 15: Raise the crate into the ceiling with a funnel, then place a portal on the wall opposite the monitor. It should have enough speed to break the monitor.

Comment: Yet another way for Chamber 15: you place blue portal on the wall opposite the monitor, then you can spray the floor with propulsion gel and run into orange portal. It will give you enough speed to hit the bottom of the screen and break it. The hard part is to get enough gel to make a nice orange road to the portal wall. You'll need multiple portions

Answer (score 4):

The TVs that you can break to win the achievement: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 11, 12, 15, 16.

Here's how to do the later ones:

> 4. Use a turret.  Blitz it and just point it at the screen...they appear to hate Wheatley.
>  5. For both, use cubes, easy enough to lift them up in the center and fling like you did yourself.
>  6. Walk in, do nothing but hit the faith plate.
>  11. Laser.
>  12. Laser.
>  15. You.
>  16. Take out 2 turrets with goo, then either fling yourself out where you put the goo through or use a funnel.  This one takes a while to nail down.

Something interesting I found is that Wheatley has a new remark for every one you break.

Answer (score 2):

There's a video on YouTube in case you still don't know how to solve some.

Comment: If you wanted to add the video to somebody else's answer feel free to propose this via the "improve this answer" button! You still get reputation points from it.

Comment: You get two rep points, actually. Thats assuming a mod lets it in.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an additional note, there's another one in Chapter 9 at the conveyor belt.

To get it, you'll have to

> Place one portal under the bomb vent, and another directly opposite the monitor, on the side of the entrance to the room.

I've uploaded a YouTube video to show this one.

**Edit:** This does not count for the achievement Smash TV.