# How many different monitors exist in Chapter 8?

Tags: achievements, portal-2

There is an achievement for smashing a certain number of different monitors in the game.  It seems like there are no possible ways to break some of the monitors, but I still haven't broken enough of them.

How many monitors exist in Chapter 8?  Is it possible to break each of those monitors (without using a glitch)?

Comment: The achievement is covered in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/how-do-i-achieve-smash-tv). Spoiler tags included.

Comment: As compared to the other question, I'm trying to get at whether any of the monitors are skippable or impossible.  No problem if the community thinks this is a dupel  :)

Comment: you should find the first bit of my answer to the suggested dupe answers this point for you - "I've now counted 16 monitors in Chapter 8, but you can ignore the first 5, so you need to break all the monitors from the one found in the test chamber numbered 1/19, up to the start of Chapter 9.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only eleven breakable monitors (exactly as many as you need for the achievement).  There are several other *un*breakable monitors, but I don't have an exact count for those.

The first ten breakable monitors are pretty straightforward once you realize what you need to do, but the last one is quite tricky even once you figure it out.  If you're short only one, that's probably it.  If you're short more than one, go back through, looking carefully at each monitor that you can't figure out how to break.  If there's nowhere to place a portal that would allow you to fling yourself or a crate at it, maybe there's something else in the level which could damage a monitor?

If you're running into *real* trouble and getting frustrated, look at [DMA57361's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/how-do-i-achieve-smash-tv/20701#20701) to a question about the achievement.  It uses spoiler tags to protect the details, but can also be used as a list of which chambers/monitors you should be looking at.